# DNS Settings and the TXT record for authorizing email sending from the domain

Tags: google, dns, email, godaddy, mailchimp

Last night, I added a DNS record to my domain to allow Mailchimp to send emails as an official/authorized source.

[image]

It doesn't seem to have totally worked, Mailchimp is sending emails but they are not being received - I believe this is because my SPF record is not properly authorizing Mailchimp's servers to send on behalf of my domain.

I did a domain check at mxtoolbox and it's showing "Multiple SPF Records Found":

[image]

Is it the ~all and -all that is causing an issue? It should be possible to have multiple TXT DNS records, right? Am I messing up the way I have added these TXT records?

I'd like to continue to be able to send email via Google/Gmail (this is working) but I also would like to authorize Mailchimp to send emails on behalf of my domain (hosted with GoDaddy)

Any suggestions for the setup I am trying to accomplish here? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed have multiple txt records  however the complaint is multiple **spf** records. If you want to relay email through both providers you need to consolidate into a single record

```
     v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:seevers.mcsv.net ~all
```

In any event you should have only 1 txt record that  starts "v=spf1"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.